# Stray first pair when writing values to dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I currently have a list of nodes (integers) saved in python, and a corresponding list of stress values (floats) also saved to a list in Python.

Using:

```
combined_list = list(zip(node_list, stress_list))
sorted_combined_list = sorted(combined_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

I now have a list of pairs, ordered by ascending node value with a corresponding stress value.

I am now trying to write these to a dictionary, where the nodes are the keys. To do this I have tried the following:

```
stress_dict = {}
for node, stress in sorted_combined_list:
    stress_dict[node] = stress
```

When I print `stress_dict` the output is what I would expect, with the exception that the first key value pair is a seemingly random node - the output looks as follows:

```
{40632320: 0.0, 2: 0.169, 3: 0.0, 4: ....}
```

Does anyone know what I may have missed, or why this is the case? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that the random node is not in your `node_list`?

Comment: When I print sorted_combined_list, the output is as follows: [(2, 0.169), (3, 0.0), (4,... which seems reasonable

Comment: Please share your input data (`node_list` and `stress_list`), we will try to analyze and solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your response - what is the best way to share this data? Post a sample of it here?